# Size of a Link opening in a new tab

Tags: html

What is a custom HTML code for having a link (say abc123.com) which is of certain size and color and which opens in a new/blank tab.

Have tried blank standalone with link but need to know how to change the size and font color of the the link word "SUBMIT"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you need is to use the anchor tab which is  In this to put the url is to use the href attribute and then the url. To chance the color and size and all of that would require you to have a class or id for the link. Then using CSS, you could format this link. use the color tag to change text color, and font-size to change the font size. For example, this is what I would do.

```html
<style>
.link {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
<a href="abc123.com" class="link">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if that isn't what you want, you could try using a button and then an onclick function that opens a new link in a new tab. Try this code :

```js
function submit() {
window.open('abc123.com');
}
```

```html
<style>
.submit-button {
outline: none;
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
color: blue;
font-size: 40px;
}
.submit-button:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
<button class="submit-button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```